# Japan's snow road: Where is it and when to visit?

Tags: japan, identify-this, snow

In the Internet I found interesting pictures about Japan's snow road. It seems that there are at least 10 meters of snow on this road.

[image]

Unfortunately I couldn't find out where in Japan this road is located, and when one should visit it, to find the maximum amount of snow. Additionally, I'm interested how high the amount of snow can get there, and if it is reliable in every winter.

Comment: Sorry that my answer is a bit bare-bones. But I hope it's enough to get you started!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could be the [Tateyama Kurobe Alpine Route](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e7550.html).

I was also thinking of Gassan, which is in Yamagata. Gassan has a ski season of [April to July](http://www.snowjapan.com/e/features/as-i-ski-it-3.html). The ski season isn't determined by when it starts snowing - it's determined when they've managed to get rid of enough of it so they can open up the roads!